# Urxvt cursor cutting off wide characters like 'w' and 'm'

Tags: debian, graphics, urxvt

I'm using the 14 px Gohu font, and it looks like these characters are offset one pixel to the left from the cursor which causes the cursor to ignore that part of the text when typing.

[image]

I am using bspwm + urxvt + compton.

Things I have tried:

- Disable compton
- Set cursor to underscore

This problem did not occur with the default font.

What is causing this and how is it fixed?

Comment: The font works for me in [`evilvte`](http://www.calno.com/evilvte/). What's your `urxvt` config? (I don't think Compton and `bspwm` ought to affect any of this.)

Comment: I had some issues getting the font to work just by adding the files to .fonts so I used this script https://github.com/christoffer/configs/blob/master/snippets/install-gohu-fonts-ubuntu.sh

Oops, submitting comment on enter screwed me up.

My font line is `urxvt*font: xft:GohuFont:pixelsize=14`.

Comment: I would put the rest but I haven't quite figured out copy and paste from virtualbox yet. It's just colors I copied off from someone else's config file.

Comment: I haven't used `urxvt` in ages, but pasting that one line into `.Xresources` has no effect for me: `urxvt` still starts with the default font and logs nothing to `stderr`. However, I'm on Arch Linux and I put the font in `/usr/share/fonts`, which is hopefully not relevant, but maybe there are subtleties? Last thing I can think of: Does your config set `letterSpace`?

Comment: My config is in `.Xdefaults` not `.Xresources`. I'm not 100% on the difference, this is my second day figuring out a not-Ubuntu Linux.

My first attempt to install the font was in `/usr/share/fonts` but even though `fc-cache` showed it cached new fonts, it didnt show when doing `fc-list | grep gohu`. But when I used the script above, it worked.

My config has default `letterSpace`.

Maybe I should learn Arch...

Comment: Sorry, I messed up! Since I use a plain window manager instead of a desktop environment, nothing in `.Xresources` was actually being loaded. I ran `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` and sure enough `urxvt` did set the font correctly. It [looks fine on mine](http://i.imgur.com/UIEp72B.png) though... I'm running out of ideas now. (By the way, `X[defaults|resources]` are just different names for essentially the same thing. Arch [calls it `.Xresources`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources), hence why I used that.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in that letter space! Just ran into this issue and looked at the man page for a second but to clear any confusion the property is NOT applied as  so (in .Xresources)

```
URxvt*font: xft:GohuFont:pixelsize=14:letterSpace:3
```

Its actually just a property of URxvt, not the specifically the font.

```
URxvt.letterSpace:3
```

I'm on a minimal debian install using URxvt

Comment: What, exactly, are you saying about `URxvt.letterSpace:3`? Should the user add *both* lines to their `.Xresources` file?

Comment: The first line I have the property being set at the end, which in my experience didn't do anything. Of course a user would have both lines in their .Xresources, but without :letterSpace at the end of the first line.